# What does it mean for complexes of a group to be conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

This pertains to [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D#page/n7/mode/2up).
In the current context, a *complex* of a group is simply a subset of the group's set. The group under discussion is $\mathfrak{G}.$

In **1B2 $\S$ 3.1** (page 183) we are told:

> For a given complex $\mathfrak{K},$ the complexes of the form $G^{-1}\mathfrak{K}G,G\in\mathfrak{G}$ are called the *conjugates* or *transforms of $\mathfrak{K}$ (under $\mathfrak{G}$)*. If $\mathfrak{K}$ is conjugate only to itself, then $\mathfrak{K}$ is said to be *normal* or *invariant* in $\mathfrak{G}.$

First of all, they don't explain what it means for one complex to be conjugate to another, or to itself. I assume this means, for example, $G^{-1}\mathfrak{K}G=\mathfrak{K};$ but I'm not certain if it means this holds for all $G\in\mathfrak{G},$ or for some, possibly proper subset of $\mathfrak{G}$.

*So my first question is, what does it mean to say two complexes are conjugate?*

Then in **$\S$ 3.4** (page 185) we find:

> If $\mathfrak{U}$ is a subgroup of $\mathfrak{G}$, the conjugate complexes $\mathfrak{G}^{-1}G,G\in\mathfrak{G}$ are also subgroups of $\mathfrak{G}.$

Is this a typographical error, and perhaps it should be $G^{-1}\mathfrak{K}G,G\in\mathfrak{G}$ rather than $\mathfrak{G}^{-1}G,G\in\mathfrak{G}?$ If not then what does the statement mean?

The discussion almost certainly relates to what are sometimes called similarity transformations, in the context of matrices, eigenvectors and eigenvalues.  Since I am somewhat familiar with such applications, an example along those lines might be helpful.

Comment: Your link loads forever. Please describe what you are reading more directly.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that complexes $U$ and $V$ are said to be conjugate if there exists a $g \in \mathfrak G$ such that $V = g U g^{-1}$. (Note that I'm not going to use capital letters for single elements.)

Comment: I don't know if this will help,  It links to the PDF file.  It will be difficult for me to extract the pertinent context  from the terse discussion.  https://archive.org/download/MyStuff38/Behnke,%20Bachmann,%20Fladt%20&%20Suss%20[Eds.]%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1,%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra[MIT%20Press,%20555p].pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first equation in $\S$IB2.6.1 (Page 194) apparently clarifies this.  They do intend that $G^{-1}\mathfrak{K}G=\mathfrak{K}$ holds for all $G\in\mathfrak{G}.$

I also believe $\mathfrak{G}^{-1}G,G\in\mathfrak{G}$ is a typo.  Though it may be some cryptic sideways way of saying what they claim it means.

I have not given the intervening discussion rigorous consideration, so I am going to leave this open in case someone wishes to challenge my conclusion.

[image]